# pip install geopandas: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: python, geopandas

I try to install geopandas package using `pip install geopandas` on the Jupyter notebook. However, I get the error *ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.*
I also installed `gevent` using `pip install gevent --pre`, and my current python version is 3.8.5. However, nothing has worked yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same issue when I tried to `pip install geopandas`. A few post recommended installation of dependencies in a precise sequence but they all failed (for me) because of `fiona`.

In enventually chose to install anaconda and create a virtual environment for an installation of `geopandas` via conda.

**Create a virtual environement**

```
conda create -n geo_env
```

Then activate you environement:

```
activate geo_env
```

**Install Geopandas**

```
conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas
```

Also, make sure to have `jupyter` and `nb_conda_kernels` plus have `ipykernel`.

**Alternative**
If you do not want to install anaconda, you could try the same procedure as above, i.e.

1. Create a virtual environemnt (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)
2. `pip install geopandas`

Comment: Although the new kernel has appeared in the Jupyter notebook, it cannot connect to the server. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: There can be many reasons. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955563/jupyter-notebook-cannot-connect-to-kernel